# What is the trigger for Jenkins extended email notification

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

What is the trigger for Jenkins extended email notification plugin? I have in executed shell of the job path to bash script. And somewhere in this script I have notification:

> echo "Disc usage is over 90%"

but after this I have to continue script execution without exiting but right away I need just send an email notification about this event. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are almost 20 different triggers for e-mail ext. See the advanced button under the e-mail configuration. You can use either a separate script result to trigger e-mail ext or an overall build status at the time when the plugin gets triggered.

The latter better suits your situation, as it can be used along with [Text Finder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) plugin to set the overall build status to `Unstable` depending on the parsed `Disk usage` value or whatever you need. Then configure e-mail ext to send e-mail on `Unstable`.